# Background transparente em java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, jtextfield

Estou com um problema com o `background` transparente de um `JTextField`, ao mudar o conteúdo do `JTextField` ele parece que sobrepõe o texto e fica tudo misturado:

[image: exemplo do erro]

Estou setando o background assim:

```
 Field.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0f));
```

//EDIT

Consegui fazer usando a dica do @utluiz porem os numeros ficam com uns pixels brancos em volta:

[image]

Tem como deixar o fundo totalmente transparente também?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sou muito bom com GUI, mas consegui reproduzir o problema e resolver com o método `repaint()` no componente "pai".

Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```java
public class TextFieldTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //janela
        final JFrame janela = new JFrame("Test JTextField");

        //campo de texto
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField("Texto de Teste");
        textField.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0f));
        janela.getContentPane().add(textField);

        //listener de mudança
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                janela.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                janela.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                janela.repaint();
            }
        });

        //exibe a janela
        janela.setSize(200,  200);
        janela.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Sem o *listener*, o mesmo código apresenta o problema descrito na pergunta.

Comment: então minha estrutura é a seguinte, um borderlayout onde um a posição north dele, depois insiro um gridlayout e dentro dessa grid o JTextField, quando uso repaint no ultimo grid, não acontece nada, quando uso nesse grid superior a minha grid inferior desaparece toda

Comment: bem antes eu tinha colocado isso no fim do `main` e aconteceu isso acima, agora coloquei logo depois do `add` e não aconteceu nada, o java pede pra mudar meus `JPanel` tudo pra final

Comment: @alleen94 Não teria como você postar mais um pouco do seu código na pergunta para que eu consiga testar?

Comment: vou tentar é que esta meio bagunçado ^^

Answer (score 2):

Eu faço assim:

```
package teste;

import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Container; 
import java.awt.Font; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JRootPane; 
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Teste extends JFrame {

    private JButton fechar, mostrar;
    private JTextField campo;
    private boolean x;

    public Teste() {
        final Container tela = getContentPane();
        tela.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
        this.setTitle("Teste");
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        fechar = new JButton();
        fechar.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        fechar.setText("Fechar");
        fechar.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        fechar.setBackground(new Color(190, 190, 190));
        this.add(fechar);

        mostrar = new JButton();
        mostrar.setBounds(200, 0, 200, 200);
        mostrar.setText("Ocultar");
        mostrar.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        mostrar.setBackground(new Color(190, 190, 190));
        this.add(mostrar);

        campo = new JTextField("Campo de texto");
        campo.setBounds(150, 250, 120, 20);
        this.add(campo);

        mostrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mostrar();
            }
        });
        fechar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fechar();
            }
        });

    }

    public void fechar() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void mostrar() {

        if (!x) {
            setBackground(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f));
            mostrar.setText("Ocultar");
            x = true;
        } else {
            setBackground(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));//Deixa o frame transparente.
            mostrar.setText("Mostrar");
            x = false;
        }
        fechar.setOpaque(x);
        repaint();
    } 
}
```